# Unable to identify the apk for variant babybook-debug and device genymotion

Tags: apk, genymotion, identify

I run the App on my mobile phone has no problem;
But there is a problem when I run it on genymotion
that's the information:
Unable to identify the apk for variant babybook-debug and device genymotion-google_nexus_10___4_4_4___api_19___2560x1600-192.168.56.101:5555

How to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

You have to look to the bottom-left part of the screen and select the menu entitled "Build variants"; then select x86Debug so that your App can be executed on Genymotion.

[image] [image]